# Executar um programa python no javascript

Tags: javascript, python

```
client.on("chat", function(channel, user, message, self){
    if(message === 'Olá'){
        client.action("ythezack", user["display-name"] + " Seja bem vindo!");}
    if(message === '!Nick'){
        client.action("ythezack", "Meu nick no lol é: Sixxxty me adicione lá!")
    }
    if(message === '!MeuAmigo'){
        MeuAmigo++;
        client.action("ythezack", "Sixx já disse meu amigo " + MeuAmigo + " vezes!")}
    if(message === '!saranking'){


    }       


});
```

Fiz esse codigo em javascript, para bot na Twitch.Tv, e gostaria de saber no caso do if(message===!saranking) Seria possivel executar um codigo python ali?

Comment: Estás a correr esse código no Node ou no browser?

Comment: Node, escrevo no sublime e executo no cmd

Answer (score -1):

Podes usar o para correr commandos no Node. Não sei bem como é a lógica da tua aplicação e que encadeamentos assíncronos precisas ter mas um exemplo seria assim:

```js
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const processoPython = spawn('python',["caminho/para/ficheiro.py", arg1, arg2, ...]);

processoPython.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  // fazer algo
});

processoPython.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
  // gerir o erro
});

processoPython.on('close', (code) => {
  // o processo acabou
});
```

Para inserir na tua aplicação tens de ter em conta que as callbacks são assíncronas e lógica if/else não é. Sugiro encadear a continuação desse script após resposta do `end` ou caso o `stderr` seja chamado.